# Default move constructor of classes with reference members

Tags: c++

This is a minimal example, extracted from a larger project.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cassert> 
using namespace std; 


class Data
{
    int value_; 
public:
    int const& value = value_;

    Data(int init)
    {
        value_ = init; 
        assert(value == value_);
    }

    //Data(Data const& other) 
    //{
    //  value_ = other.value_;
    //}
    // Data(Data && other) = default; 

    ~Data()
    {
        assert(value == value_); 
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> datas; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        datas.push_back(Data(i));
    }
}
```

Assertion in destructor fails at some point; at which point I can't tell. I am dumbfounded. Providing copy c-tor works, but then enabling default move-ctor fails again.

How does default move/copy c-tor handles such references? I can't analyze with debugger what is happening behind the scenes.
Is using public const& a valid way in C++ to provide a getter?

Comment: A reference, `const` or not, cannot be reseated. This makes a mess of the assignment operator. For that reason alone I'd write off this idea as a good getter replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default copy-constructor

```
Data(Data const&) = default;
```

is mostly equivalent to:

```
Data(Data const& rhs) :
    value_(rhs.value_), // Copy value
    value(rhs.value)    // alias the same value as rhs.value, so probably rhs.value_ 
{
}
```

So you don't point on internal member as you expect.

Same for default move constructor with some `std::move`.

Comment: That makes so much sense. I think the most confusing part was what cplusplusrat pointed out: inline initialization is entirely ignored by the implicit copy and move constructors. This is so un-intuitive.

Comment: @MkjG It would be very counter-intuitive if copy constructor used default member initialisers instead of copying the members.

Answer (score 3):

> How does default move/copy c-tor handles such references?

The member of the copy will refer to the same object which the member of the source refers to.

In this case the referred object is another member. So, if you copy `B` from `A`, then the reference member of `B` will refer to the object member of `A`, because that is what the reference member of `A` referred to. if `A` is destroyed, that reference member of `B` will be left danging and accessing the object (which no longer exists) through it has undefined behaviour.

Indeed, you can use a custom copy / move constructors in order to initialise the reference to refer to some other object, but reference to a member is in general quite useless.

> Is using public const& a valid way in C++ to provide a getter?

It is not a good solution.

Comment: Worth a clarification. When invoking a default copy ctor for a struct, I am assuming that the inline initialization is entirely ignored. Here is a small example to demonstrate this. http://cpp.sh/4hxlp

Comment: @cplusplusrat Indeed. Default member initialisers are not used by the implicit copy and move constructors.